# Subprocess magick command system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, subprocess, imagemagick, mogrify

I am trying to run command line using subprocess in python and this is my try

```
import subprocess

#magick mogrify -path C:/Users/Future/Desktop/results -format PNG C:/Users/Future/Desktop/IDs/*.tiff

#Use 'subprocess.run(["magick", "-path", variable, "-format", "png", variable])'
source_path = "C:/Users/Future/Desktop/IDs/*.tiff"
target_path = "C:/Users/Future/Desktop/results"


subprocess.call(["magick mogrify", "-path", target_path, "-format", "PNG", source_path])
```

The code was created with the help of Mr. @MarkSetchell
I got an error like that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Future\Desktop\demo.py", line 52, in <module>
    subprocess.call(["magick mogrify", "-path", target_path, "-format", "PNG", source_path])
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 349, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I also tried to use `run` instead of `call` but the same problem.

This is my final try

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil
import subprocess

BASE_DIR = Path.cwd()
IDs_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'IDs'
RESULTS_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'Results'

try:
    shutil.rmtree(RESULTS_DIR)
except OSError as e:
    pass

RESULTS_DIR.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

#source_path = "C:/Users/Future/Desktop/IDs/*.tiff"
#target_path = "C:/Users/Future/Desktop/results"

#Path(dir_name) / output_folder / str(base_filename + suffix)

#subprocess.run(["magick", "mogrify", "-path", RESULTS_DIR, "-format", "PNG", IDs_DIR + "/*tiff"])
subprocess.run(["magick", "mogrify", "-path", RESULTS_DIR, "-format", "PNG", Path(IDs_DIR) / str("*tiff")])
```

Comment: You need to separate `magick` from `mogrify` so that each part is a separate entity in the list `subprocess.call(["magick", "mogrify"...`

Comment: Can I control specific suffixes to the output files? I mean I need to add filename_Page_0, something like that

Comment: You can either) do them all in one go with `mogrify` and have less control over the names, or b) do them individually with `magick INPUT OUTPUT` running a separate subprocess for each one and having full control over the names.

Comment: Also, I think you need to use `str(RESULTS_DIR)` in your command to make the PosixPath into a string that IM can understand.

Comment: Will the code be fast as the existing one? as this means a lot of loops.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how many files you have, how big they are, or how fast your CPU is, or how many cores you have, or how fast your disk is, or how much memory you have, or how fast the existing code is...

Comment: Thank you very much. Last question in this topic. Is it possible to resize the output images with the same command?

Comment: I tried `subprocess.run(['magick', 'mogrify', '-path', str(RESULTS_DIR), '-format', 'PNG', Path(IDs_DIR) / str('*tiff'), '-quality', '100', '-resize', '1808x1189'])`, the code works but I didn't get the desried dimensions. Any idea?

Comment: It seems the order is very important. I used this line and worked very well and as expected `subprocess.call(['magick', tiff_file, '-quality', '100', '-resize', '1808x1189', tiff_file.replace('.tiff','') + '_Page_%d.png'])`

Comment: Is it possible to limit the pages to extract to two pages only as I found some tiffs with more than two pages?